# What part of the skin is damaged under sun exposure?

Tags: cancer, skin, dna-damage, uv, melanin

How exactly does extensive sun exposure lead to skin damage and increase cancer risk. In which part of the skin is the sun doing the most damage. Is it in the epidermis or beneath ? I would like to know if UV-protective tattoos would be possible.

Comment: Hi Roy; welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal, Roy, is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail and it will likely be received more positively by out community. Thanks!

Comment: Roy, @theforestecologist is completely correct. Long story short, though, tattoos **are** a kind of skin damage, and [may cause cancer](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1470204511703400).

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRD-xvlhGMc - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9K6gjR07Po